# Question regarding Primal simplex method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

Quick question regarding the Primal Simplex Method:

> How do you use the Primal Simplex Method when you have to start with a specific basis?

Suppose we wish to use the Primal Simplex method on the following minimization problem in standard form:
$$\text{min}\quad 2x_1+2x_2+2x_3$$
$$\text{s.t. }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$2x_1+4x_3+s_1=4$$
$$2x_2+2x_3+s_2=3$$
$$3x_1+x_2+x_3−s_3=8$$
$$x_i,s_i\ge0,\forall i$$
We have to start with the basic variables $BV=(x_1,s_2,s_3)
$, and I have a hard time with the fact that usually I would start with the basis consisting of our slack variables, however, in this example this isn't the case. A walkthrough of understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A side note: Usually you start with $(s_1,s_2,a_3)=(4,3,8)$, where $a_3$ is the artificial variable of the third contraint.

Comment: Btw, what are the values of basis?

Comment: We don't need to know that @callculus42, we can actually solve for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the original standardized model (with the fixed third constraint, $a_3$ is analogous to $s_3$),
$$\text{min}\quad z=2x_1+2x_2+2x_3+Ma_3$$
$$\text{s.t. }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$2x_1+4x_3+s_1=4$$
$$2x_2+2x_3+s_2=3$$
$$3x_1+x_2+x_3−e_3+a_3=8$$

with the Basic Variables $=\{x_1, s_2,a_3\}$. This means $x_2=x_3=s_1=e_1=0$. Let's consider the first constraint:
$$2x_1+4x_3+s_1=4$$
$$2x_1+0+0=4$$
$$x_1=2$$

Then let's consider the second constraint:
$$2x_2+2x_3+s_2=3$$
$$0+0+s_2=3$$
$$s_2=3$$

The third constraint:
$$3x_1+x_2+x_3-e_3+a_3=8$$
$$6+0+0-0+a_3=8$$
$$a_3=2$$

We can the put this into the Simplex tableau as such:
\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & e_3 & s_1 & s_2 & a_3 & RHS \\
\hline z & 1 & 0 &  &  &  &  & 0 & 0 & 2M+4 \\ \hline
     x_1 & 0 & 1 &  &  &  &  & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
     s_2 & 0 & 0 &  &  &  &  & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
     a_3 & 0 & 0 &  &  &  &  & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

If we match our basic variables to our original equations like so:
$$\text{min}\quad z-2x_1-2x_2-2x_3+0+0+0-Ma_3=0$$
$$x_1\longrightarrow 2x_1+0x_2+4x_3+s_1+0+0+0=4$$
$$s_2\longrightarrow 0x_1+2x_2+2x_3+0+s_2+0+0=3$$
$$a_3\longrightarrow 3x_1+x_2+x_3+0+0−e_3+a_3=8$$

We can do Gaussian Elimination from this to get a system of equations that are the reduced costs and coefficients of the basis we are trying to achieve to get the following tableau:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & e_3 & s_2 & a_3 & RHS \\
\hline z & 1 & 0 & M-2 & -5M+2 & -\frac{3}{2}M & -M & 0 & 0 & 2M+4 \\ \hline
     x_1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
     s_2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
     a_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -5 & -\frac{3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

From here, since $M$ is the "largest" number in $\Bbb R$, we would proceed to pivot the $x_2$ column with the $s_2$ row with the Simplex Method in tableau form.